# Use SOAP API for Custom Activity in Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api, custom-activity

I want to create a custom activity in journey builder to send an SMS to customers.

I have gone through the salesforce marketing cloud document and they're mentioned that we can only use REST API in Custom activity.

I want to use SOAP API to create a custom Activity. Is it possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As per the salesforce marketing cloud API doc, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/rest.htm
We have a predefined custom activity format. As per the marketing cloud, The REST API  can be used to extend Journey Builder functionality. Can I Use SOAP API to send an SMS from the custom activity in the journey?